# MCU to talk to 5 (or more) serials

Tags: microcontroller, spi, serial, multiplexer, rs232

I have a project where I need to talk to 5 devices over serial (RS232 to be precise).
At 57k Baud. With a polling frequency that is as high as possible.

The first step is probably to convert from RS232 to TTL levels (via MAX232).
Then I see the following possible options:

1. The easiest would be to just use a MCU that has enough hardware serials. The Teensy 4+ comes to mind. Anything less expensive and still easy to deal with?
2. Use a muxer to switch between the different serials (MC14551B? but I didn't find many examples). The big drawback is that this restricts the polling frequency as the MCU can only talk to one serial at a time.
3. Have some external component act as a serial extender via SPI/I2C (similar to [this project](https://www.instructables.com/SPI-to-4-x-UART-Bridge-MULTIUART/)). I am wondering if there is a ready-made standard component for this. And whether 5*57k Baud => 285k Baud will work without problems via SPI/I2C. (I assume SPI: yes, I2C: maybe?)
4. Have a MCU per serial and another MCU that coordinates between those MCUs. But this feels rather complex and painful.

Have I missed other options?
Which path would you pursue?

Comment: Use RS-485/422 as a single bus to all of the devices (if the devices are capable, of course)

Comment: tcurdt - Hi, IMHO you need to decide whether *sequential* polling (your option 2) would meet your stated "polling frequency that is as high as possible" requirement. Even better if the minimum practical polling frequency can be quantified e.g. add info about polling command data size (to device), polling response data size (from device), idle time waiting for the device to respond to the MCU poll etc. - all that info is needed to calculate how long one of the devices would "occupy" the shared MCU serial port and therefore whether multiplexing is an option for you at all. Can you add more info?

Comment: 1) Teensy is not a MCU, it is a module/boaord which contains MCU - big difference. 2) Mux is possible if your protocol allows it 3) I2C/SPI UARTs exist and are possible 4) MCU per serial is possible. But really, MCUs large enough to habe 5+ UARTs do exist.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wish that was possible but the devices use RS232

Comment: @Justme Not sure the MCU/board distinction is relevant for the question - but you are of course correct. If you have some recommendations for e.g. SPI UART/RS232 transceiver or the MCUs that would be very helpful.

Comment: @SamGibson The minimum polling frequency is a little hard to quantify. It's a modbus request/response of a single word size register. If there was a data point every 100ms it would be ideal. More than 500ms it will become problematic to say the very least.

Comment: Depending on the application requirements, I would consider having a "local" controller on each device, communicating serially with the device, and also sitting on a common multidrop bus connected to a master. This will make an extendable topology and will off-load the device control specifics from the main "business logic" implemented on the master.

Comment: @tcurdt - Thanks for the reply. So using that info, and your knowledge of the external device (including its response time to a poll), you can decide whether your option 2 (sequential polling) is an option or not.  If that *is* an option regarding the overall polling frequency, I would wonder why there is a need to consider anything else (more complex) e.g. extendability? If multiplexing isn't an option (i.e. overall polling frequency is too low) then that needs to be updated in the question. Depending on your calculation & decision here, next steps "fall out". I'll stop here. Best of luck!

Comment: Back in 2014 I used a series of MAX3111's on an SPI bus to do this.  I wasn't pushing any speed limits, but it did work fine.

Comment: It is relevant as there is no MCU called Teensy (or Arduino) as these are developement boards with various MCUs and you ask for a MCU which is a chip. It's Modbus so you only need to communicate with one device at one given moment so maybe you don't need 5 UARTs.

Comment: @tcurdt approx 12 bytes for the request and 12 bytes per response? And you need one every 20ms? So that's like 4800 bits per second. So one bus (at 57600) is fast enough. In fact it's more than 10 times as fast as you need it to be.  What is the problem with multiplexing? (This is why having actual numbers is good)

Comment: I miscalculated - it is 12000 bits per second

Comment: @tcurdt Back in the day, we would either use a weird programmable TCU like the NS32201, or else something like the [16C55x](https://www.ti.com/product/TL16C554A) device. The latter includes a 16-byte FIFO for each peripheral, which relieves the load on interrupts. I have supported up to 8 RS-232 ports at 115kbps without any difficulty using a single ancient MCU. It's not hard to get right. I'm not sure I understand the problem, I guess.

Comment: Look at the Infineon/Cypress PSoC 4,5 or 6 MCU. I'm using a PSoC 6 and it has plenty of communication blocks.